# How to re-render every time state changes with API call limit?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Edit: People from FUTURE: check out this video -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyxFSkh2wug
and the article provided by Leonardo.

I have a searchbar component and a stockchart component that are both children of the Parent component. I want to re-render the stockchart every time a key is entered in the search bar. I am new to react so please bear with my code.

I tried a shouldComponentUpdate and it made too many API calls. In the CorrectRender function, I tried to return the StockChart everytime ticker changed but it didn't work.

I've tried my best to describe the methods I wrote, please feel free to ask any questions.

This is the Parent component, I'm calling this inside App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StockChart from './StockChart';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';


// Renders stockChart when value is entered
// I tried to re-render by using a current and previousTicker symbols but it didn't work.

function CorrectRender(props, oldtick) {
    const ticker = props.props;
    console.log("props", props)
    const previousTicker = props.oldtick;
    if (ticker.length > 0 && previousTicker !== ticker) {
        return <div>
            <p>{ticker}</p>
            <StockChart stockSymbol = {ticker} previousTicker={previousTicker}/>
        </div>
    }
    return null;
    }

export class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockSymbol: '',
            previousTicker: ''
        }
        this.callbackFunction = this.callbackFunction.bind(this);
    }


    shaveData(value) {
        let value1 = value.split(`,`);
        value = value1[0];
        this.setState({
            stockSymbol: value,
        });
    }



    callbackFunction(sS)  {
        this.setState({ previousTicker: this.state.stockSymbol});
        this.shaveData(sS);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar parentCallback = {this.callbackFunction}/>
                <CorrectRender props={this.state.stockSymbol} oldtick={this.state.previousTicker}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

This is the SEARCHBAR component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';



export class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: ' ',
            tickerList: [],
        }
    }



    // Get a list of tickers from an API, this is not the api call that is being overused
    // I want the data to show to the user as "Ticker, Company name" which is what the second (.then) is doing
    fetchTickers(stockSymbol) {
        const pointer = this;
        let arr = [];
        console.log(stockSymbol);
        let url = `https://ticker-2e1ica8b9.now.sh/keyword/${stockSymbol}`;

        fetch(url) 
            .then( function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then ( function(data) {
                for (var key in data) {
                    arr.push(data[key]['symbol'] + ", "+ data[key]['name'])
                };

                pointer.setState({
                    tickerList: arr
                })
            }

            )
    }

    // this is for handling keys in the search bar and rendering new results based on the 
    critera
    textChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        let arr = [];
        if (value.length > 0) {
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i');
            this.fetchTickers(value);
            arr = this.state.tickerList.sort().filter(tick => regex.test(tick));
        }
        this.setState({
            tickerList: arr,
            search: value
        });
    }


    // This will be called when an option is chosen by user
    tickerChosen(value) {
        let value1 = value.split(`,`);
        value = value1[0];
        this.setState({
            search: value,
            tickerList: []
        });



    };


    // list of suggestions on user side based on criteria
    tickerSuggestions () {
        const { tickerList } = this.state;
        if (tickerList.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {tickerList.map((ticker) => <li key={ticker} onClick={() =>  {this.props.parentCallback(ticker); this.tickerChosen(ticker);} }>{ticker}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    };



    render() {
        const { search } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className= 'SearchBar'>
                <input value = { search } onChange={this.textChange} type='text' />
                {this.tickerSuggestions()}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchBar
```

This is the StockChart component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';


class StockChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockXValues: [],
            stockYValues: [],
            stockSymbol: '',

        }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStock();
}

fetchStock() {
    const pointer = this;
    const symbol = this.props.stockSymbol;

    const API_KEY = `X`;
    let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${symbol}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${API_KEY}`;

    let StockXValuesFunc = [];
    let StockYValuesFunc = [];



    fetch(API_Call)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                for (var key in data['Time Series (Daily)']) {
                    StockXValuesFunc.push(key);
                    StockYValuesFunc.push(data['Time Series (Daily)']
                    [key]['4. close']);
                }
                pointer.setState({
                    stockXValues: StockXValuesFunc,
                    stockYValues: StockYValuesFunc,
                });


            }
        )

}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>{this.props.stockSymbol}</h2>
        <Plot
            data={[
            {
                x: this.state.stockXValues,
                y: this.state.stockYValues,
                type: 'scatter',
                mode: 'lines+markers',
                marker: {color: 'red'},
            },
            ]}
            layout={ {width: 720, height: 440, title: 'Closing Price over the last 100 days'} }
        />
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Export default StockChart;

Comment: why not using a throttle function for your call ? also for your chart it may have an update function instead of rerendering it all

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a good explanation on how to throttle and avoid doing so many API calls:
[Improve your react app performance by using throttling and debouncing](https://blog.bitsrc.io/improve-your-react-app-performance-by-using-throttling-and-debouncing-101afbe9055)

Comment: Instead of just providing links to external sites, you should also provide the brief about solution here because links can go stale over time. So please consider doing that too.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I also found a video on the subject, which I updated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **Throttling** or **Debouncing**

**Throttling** executes a given function after a specified amount of time has elapsed.

**Debouncing** enforces that a function will not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed since its last call.
In debouncing, it ignores all calls to a function and waits until the function has stopped being called for a specified amount of time.

To apply throttling or debouncing you can use npm packages underscore,lodash or rxjs.

**Throttling Example**

```
    // ...
import { throttle } from lodash;
class autocomp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: []
        }
       this.handleInputThrottled = throttle(this.handleInput, 100)
    }
    handleInput = evt => {
        const value = evt.target.value
        const filteredRes = data.filter((item)=> {
            // algorithm to search through the `data` array
        })
        this.setState({ results: filteredRes })
    }
    render() {
        let { results } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='autocomp_wrapper'>
                <input placeholder="Enter your search.." onChange={this.handleInputThrottled} />
                <div>
                    {results.map(result=>{result})}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Debouncing Example**

```
    // ...
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
class autocomp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: []
        }
       this.handleInputThrottled = debounce(this.handleInput, 100)
    }
    handleInput = evt => {
        const value = evt.target.value
        const filteredRes = data.filter((item)=> {
            // algorithm to search through the `data` array
        })
        this.setState({ results: filteredRes })
    }
    render() {
        let { results } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='autocomp_wrapper'>
                <input placeholder="Enter your search.." onChange={this.handleInputThrottled} />
                <div>
                    {results.map(result=>{result})}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```